# How to do i need to implemnet paging for jquery grid

Tags: jquery

I have a gird with user data around like 5000 users in the grid.
right now I am displaying all the users in the grid. but I need to make it like only 500 user for page.

So i need to implement paging in the grid with previous and next button on the bottom of the page.

Can any body tell me how to do this?

Comment: Is 500 still not quite a lot?  Any more than you can see on the screen I would consider too much.

Comment: Just I made it as 500 for example.. actually i ned 50 per page..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Fluid Pager Widget](http://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/fluid/Pager+API), from their Infusion framework, handles this issue really elegantly on the client side.

If you want to send fewer than 5k records to the browser at a time, you would still need to bake that intelligence into your server-side code.